# Change relationship segue order of appearance in WatchKit

Tags: xcode, watchkit, xcode-storyboard, watchos

Current storyboard looks like this:

[image: current storyboard]

The above picture shows segue from main screen to settings screen.

I still want the `mainView` to appear as initial interface controller. However, can I reorder the settings screen to appear left of the `MainView` instead of right. In other words, upon launching the app, `MainView` shows up first and upon swiping to the left the settings screen comes up from right. I want the settings screen to come from left upon swiping to the right.

Like this

[image: desired storyboard]

Comment: You want to switch view controllers by swiping? This has nothing to do with the storyboard. You can move around the view controllers in the storyboard by clicking and dragging on where it says `Interface Controller` if you find that more suiting for designing in the interface builder but that won't have any effect on your app running on the watch.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth Thank you! I'm trying to get `MainView` to load first however, when I swipe left, I want the `SettingsView` screen to come up. Currently the `SettingsView` comes up when I swipe right. Please let me know if I was clear.

Comment: I don’t have a lot of xp with WatchKit but I’m assuming that it transitions when swiping to the right because it looks like it is a navigation controller-like UI. You will probably have to create a custom transition. I don’t know if one can do that though.